# Unable to get details from both the tables in sas using join statement

Tags: sas

I am using the below code but in the final output I am not able to get the name in the first entry where income is 234234. How do I get name entry here.

```
data names;
 input name $ age;
 datalines;
  John 10
  Mary 12
  Sally 12
  Fred 1
  Paul 2
 ;
run;

data check;
 input name $ income;
 datalines;
  Mary 121212
  Fred 334343
  Ben 234234
 ;

 Proc sql;
 title 'Inner Join';
 create table common_names as 
 select * from names as n right join check as c on
 n.name = c.name;
 run;

 Proc print data = common_names;
 run;


Output

Inner Join
Obs name    age income
1       .   234234
2   Fred    1   334343
3   Mary    12  121212
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot create two variables with the same name, in this case the variable NAME.  So either create two variables

```
select n.name as name1, c.name as name2, ....
```

or use the `COALESCE()` function to create a single variable.

```
select coalesce(n.name,c.name) as name, ....
```

You might also what to look at SAS's `NATURAL` join.  That will link tables on variables with the same name and automatically coalesce the key variable values.

```
create table common_names as
  select *
  from names as n
  natural right join check as c
;
```